# Why do my attempts at asking questions always fail?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I don't know why my question is not accepted. Here is my question; are there any problems with it?

> currently i developing a website using zen-cart. i want user must pay
>   when they sign up on my site. anyone know how to set up this feature?
>
> on admin page i only found payment module for shopping cart not for
>   pay on sign up.   and also is there any plugin or module to solve my
>   problem

Comment: This particular question doesn't seem programming related, so even if it did get posted I would bet it gets closed as "not a real question" or "off-topic"

Comment: To enhance your use of the Stack, make sure you read the [faq], [ask] and [about] pages. This will boost the quality of your Questions and consequently the quality of the Answers you receive.

Comment: so thats why (maybe) my previous question is accepted because i had line of code on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> anyone know how to set up this feature?

Assisting you with setting up this feature through a user interface is beyond the purview of Stack Overflow, which deals with programming questions. You might want to consult the help or documentation for the CMS you are using.

> and also is there any plugin or module to solve my problem

Product recommendation questions are *also* off topic here, although if you were to narrow down your problem to:

- What you are trying to accomplish
- The code you are currently using to accomplish it
- The problems with your current approach/attempt

it is possible that someone may suggest a library/plugin/framework that solves the problem.

To give you an idea of what is on topic here: if you were programming an implementation of this feature and ran into problems, a question regarding *that* would be more on topic here (provided of course that you follow [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for asking questions).

As a minor nitpick, you should try to remember to capitalise your sentences; this makes your question look more professional and improves readability. Other users will occasionally edit and patch this up for you though.

Answer (score 4):

With StackOverflow it helps to give only relevant information and all relevant information.  It would be useful in this case to explain what you have tried, what solution you are thinking about.

This site is not intended to have free help developing applications, but rather is intended to have a community to help each other out with general knowledge.

It is important to show initiative on your own part.